# Reusing an anonymous parameter in a prepared statement

Tags: java, hibernate

I am customizing the insert SQL generated by hibernate and have hit an issue.  When Hibernate generates the query by itself, it inserts data into the first two columns of the table, but this causes a database error since all four columns of the table are non-nullable.  For the insert to be performed properly, it must insert the same data into two columns of the new record.  This means that I need Hibernate to bind the same data to two different parameters in the query (prepared statement) that I am writing.

Is there some SQL syntax that allows me to refer to anonymous parameters bound to a prepared statement in an order different from which they are bound?

**Details**

```
REF_USER_PAGE_XREF
----------------------------------------
PK FK1 | NETWORK_ID     | VARCHAR2(100)
PK FK1 | PAGE_PATH      | VARCHAR2(1000)
       | USER_LAST_UPDT | VARCHAR2(100)
       | TMSP_LAST_UPDT | DATE

insert into 
    REF_USER_PAGE_XREF(
        NETWORK_ID, 
        PAGE_PATH, 
        TMSP_LAST_UPDT, 
        USER_LAST_UPDT) 
values (
    ?, /* want to insert the same data here */
    ?, 
    ?, /* and here */
    (select 
        to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YY') 
    from 
        dual)
```

I want to insert the same data into the first and third anonymous parameters.

***Final Answer*** (based on answer from @mdma)

```
insert into 
    REF_USER_PAGE_XREF(
        NETWORK_ID, 
        PAGE_PATH, 
        USER_LAST_UPDT, 
        TMSP_LAST_UPDT) 
select 
    Param1, 
    Param2, 
    Param1, 
    (select 
        to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YY') 
    from 
        dual) 
from 
    (select 
        ? as Param1, 
        ? as Param2
    from 
        dual) params
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

```
INSERT INTO REF_USER_ROLE_XRE
  SELECT Param1, Param2, Param1, 
    (select to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YY') from  dual)
FROM 
    (SELECT ? AS Param1, ? AS Param2) params
```