# Re-using parameters in PrepareStatement from java

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

```
private String QUERY = "(SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE year = ? and month = ?) UNION (SELECT * FROM tab2 WHERE year = ? and month = ?) UNION (SELECT * FROM tab3 WHERE year = ? and month = ?");

aPreparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(QUERY);
aPreparedStatement.setString(1, "2012");
aPreparedStatement.setString(2, "july");
aPreparedStatement.setString(3, "2012");
aPreparedStatement.setString(4, "2012");
aPreparedStatement.setString(5, "july");
aPreparedStatement.setString(6, "2012");
```

Instead of setting again and again for "?" the same arguments, is there any way we can avoid doing multiple setString methods to replace the the same in PreparedStatement?

Comment: bad copy/paste I guess since all parameters above 3 are inversed ^^.  Anyway, I think user1485859's answer is the only way to go except if you manage to rebuild your query to have less parameters.

Comment: Have you looked here? Is it appliable this approach for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924942/reusing-an-anonymous-parameter-in-a-prepared-statement

Comment: You might be able to achieve this depending on SQL server you use. Some DBs allow you to create temp table in some form and to use it later in joins.

Comment: pafau has a good temporary solution (note, you may want to have multiple such helper functions, depending on the type of the parameter, not just String). In the long run, you probably want to move away from coding SQL in your class to a framework like myBatis or Hibernate, that generally allows you to abstract this away, at least to the extent of allowing _named_ parameters that are also easier to understand.

Answer (score 6):

You could cook up a helper method, like this:

```
void setString(PreparedStatement pstmt, String s, Integer... indices) {
    for (Integer index : indices) {
        pstmt.setString(index, s);
    }
}
```

and then call:

```
setString(aPreparedStatement, "2012", 1, 3, 4, 6);
setString(aPreparedStatement, "july", 2, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot do it with standard PreparedStatements.  But I found an [Article from Java World](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2007/jw-04-jdbc.html) that can help you create your own class (NamedParameterStatement) to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using a loop.

```
for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
  aPreparedStatement.setString(2*i+1, "2012");
  aPreparedStatement.setString(2*i+2, "july");
}
```

Comment: This is not what OP want/needs, because the parameters aren't reusable in this way. Suppose that a new parameter must be set in the position 2, will you have to come up with a new math formula to reuse parameters?

Comment: I'll simply rewrite my SQL statement in the best fitting order.

Comment: It will become a problem when you work with indexes and you must respect the column index order, so it can affect performance. This indeed is not a good answer.